# Creatinine excretion

Tags: kidney

Creatinine accumulates in blood if kidneys fail to excrete it.  Does this unexcreted creatinine ever get thrown out of body? What prevents creatinine from continuously rising in the blood?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: This is better suited to Biology as it is a fundamental science concept.  On that site as well, prior research (what you've found so far) needs to be demonstrated to avoid closure.

Comment: Your question has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Creatinine is formed irreversibly and non-enzymically from creatine and phosphocreatinine and is usually assumed to be metabolically inert in humans (Wyss & Rima Kaddurah-Daouk, 2000, [Creatine and Creatinine Metabolism](https://www.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/physrev.2000.80.3.1107)): no human enzyme is known to metabolize creatinine, and this compound is normally eliminated from the body via the kidneys

> In chronic liver failure, however, "a significant quantity of creatinine is excreted into the gut, as is true of urea and uric acid, and is metabolized by gut flora" (Jones & Burnett, 1974, [Creatinine Metabolism in Humans with Decreased Renal Function: Creatinine Deficit](http://clinchem.aaccjnls.org/content/clinchem/20/9/1204.full.pdf).

This was 'news to me', and the observation about urea is also surprising, but it looks to be a very good paper.